# How to make a video play only on hover using html/css?

Tags: html, css, audio, video

I have a page with a multiple columns of videos, of which I would wish to only play and sound on hover. Much thanks.

I have tried using the hover feature in css, yet to no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use javascript for that. Assuming the videos are static, not dynamically added:

```js
const videos = document.querySelectorAll('.video');

videos.forEach(video => {
  video.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    video.play();
  });
  
  video.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    video.pause();
    video.currentTime = 0;
  });
});
```

Here you are iterating through all video elements and adding an event listener. When mouse enters within the area of the element, the video is played. When mouse leaves, video stops and the seek position sets to start or 0.

Comment: Browser needs user interaction sometimes. It means if user did not clicked anywhere on your page it won't work. And if you are inserting the elements dynamically then you need to follow different approach like listening on the parent, then check which element was the target which caused the event to be fired. Then just grab the video Id and play that video.